# Do males or females have a greater fear of deception?

Tags: deception, gender

> *Question*: Do males or females have a greater fear of deception?

The motivation for the question comes from a transgender context: I more frequently see reports of men being afraid of finding themselves attracted to a transgender woman than women being afraid of finding themselves attracted to a transgender men.  It is sometimes argued that not revealing one's transgender status is a form of deceit.

This leads me to believe that, in this context, men have a greater fear of deception than women, and I would like to know if the same is true for deceit in general.

Putting `"fear of deception" gender` into [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com.au/) or [PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed) didn't help me find anything useful.  I'm not sure where else I should look.

Comment: I suspect that this is subjective to culture

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because *I more frequently see reports of men being afraid of finding themselves attracted to a transgender woman than women being afraid of finding themselves attracted to a transgender men.* has many facets to be examined - one being the number of people and sex being transgender.  what is the ratio of transgender men to women for example

Comment: The question is *Do males or females have a greater fear of deception?*.  I also mention my motivation for asking the question (but that's not the question [deception in general]).  It seems like there may be quantitative research on this topic, only I'm not sure what to look for.